# Is there any way to use get_sidebar in Function?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create my own sidebar function that only shows the sidebar if a certain variable is not shown.  This works in a template file but not in a function in functions.php

```
    function my_sidebar(){
        if(($layout == 'left') || ($layout == 'right')){
            get_sidebar();
        }
    }
```

This simply shows nothing when using `my_sidebar();`

Im just trying to create a reusable function for my templates.

Comment: Where/how is `$layout` set?  You may need to pass it as an argument to your function, or declare it as a global.

Comment: `$layout = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_page_layout', true );
` and `global $post` is set in the page template.

Comment: $layout is set in the template.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question, yes, get_sidebar will work in a function in functions.php.  The problem I was having was that my meta data wasn't available to the function even though I was using`global $post` in the template before my `my_sidebar();` call.  The solution was to add the global post object to my function as well as the layout variable.

```
function my_sidebar(){
global $post;
  $layout = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_page_layout', true );
  if(($layout == 'left') || ($layout == 'right')){
  get_sidebar();
}
}
```

and to make it more concise I changed the if statement:

```
function my_sidebar(){
global $post;
  $layout = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_page_layout', true );
  if($layout !='none'){
  get_sidebar();
}
}
```

Thanks.